# Merging Linked Lists using C

Tags: c, merge, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am unable to understand why my code is not working of **merging two sorted linked list**

C Code:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* mergeLists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {
    
SinglyLinkedListNode *temp,*ptr1,*ptr2;

//Merging

      temp=head1;
      while(temp!=NULL)                                 
          temp=temp->next;          

          temp->next=head2;
           temp=head1;
             

                             //Sorting
    int tem;
      
      ptr1=head1;
      
      while(ptr1->next != NULL){                          
          
          ptr2 = ptr1->next;
             while(ptr2 != NULL){
          if((ptr1->data)>(ptr2->data)){
           tem             =   ptr1->data;
           ptr1->data       =   ptr2->data;
           ptr2->data       =   tem;
     }
       ptr2=ptr2->next;
 }
          
          ptr1=ptr1->next;
      }

        return head1;  

}
```

Comment: *Does not work* just means nothing. Please say exactly what happens, with a minimal `main` containing initialized lists and the expected and actual input. Said differently please give a true [mcve] that we can reproduce.

Comment: `while(temp!=NULL) temp=temp->next;` leaves `temp == NULL`.  THe next line is `temp->next = head2`, which tries to dereference NULL.  Perhaps your cut and paste failed to included braces.  Does "is not working" mean "run time segfault"?

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(temp!=NULL)                                 
      temp=temp->next;          

      temp->next=head2;
       temp=head1;
```

Is *very* different than:

```
while(temp!=NULL) {                               
      temp=temp->next;          
      temp->next=head2;
      temp=head1;
}
```

Braces matter, indentation does not (except to the human reader).

But there's still a logic error there.  You probably intended to walk to the end of the first list and attach the second list to it, but you went too far.  Perhaps you want `while(temp->next != NULL)` (you will need to add a check that temp is not null before you enter such a loop).

Comment: :)
I just forget to take a check on looping and now it passes all testcases.
while(temp->next!=NULL) {                               
      temp=temp->next;  
}        
      temp->next=head2;
      temp=head1;